# Does django server support url callbacks (webhooks)?

Tags: django, url, callback, webhooks

I am trying to implement url callbacks. And trying to test it. But seems like it is not working. I have been following [this](http://progrium.com/blog/2012/12/06/async-http-responses-with-response-redirection/) article for callbacks implementation.

I have defined two urls in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^agent205', 'agent205.views.test'),
    url(r'^agent206', 'agent205.views.test2'),
)
```

and their views in views.py

```
__author__ = 'rai'
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render_to_response, render
from  django.http.request import HttpRequest
import urllib, urllib2, json
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import json
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    data = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
    print request.body
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')

@csrf_exempt
def test2(request):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(request.body), content_type='application/json')
```

Then I test from postman like

[image]

I am getting HTTP 200 OK response instead of getting 202 Accepted. What should I do for callback to work? Or am I missing something

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. I don't see in what sense this is a "callback" - it just seems like a standard JSON response. And I don't understand where your difficulty is.

Comment: Just a comment, but to make your life a lot easier, I'd recommend checking out PyDanny's Django Web Hooks app: https://github.com/pydanny/dj-webhooks

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is to return a 202 HTTP status code instead of the default 200, you could try to use the `status` parameter as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    data = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
    print request.body
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json', status=202)
```

Comment: No it is about that. It is about How would i know that my callback url is accepted or not?